# How can I connect to a database on an external ip?

Tags: php, mysql, ip, external

I would like to connect to a database with an external ip of the pc on which the server, for example:

```
<? $db_host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" //external ip
$db_user = "user"; $db_password = "password"; $db_database = "database"; 
$conn = "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_database;charset=utf8mb4"; try {$db = new PDO($conn , "$db_user", "$db_password");}catch(PDOException $e) {echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();}?>
```

So, can you do that? And if so, how can I do it?
Thanks everyone for help;)

P.s: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Where is this server? Is it a hosting company; the cloud; a server you own etc?

Comment: Do you get any error when you tried this ?

Comment: @w0051977 The server is my Rpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Check Your Public IP Address [ `Public Ip Means External Ip Address`] From Here : https://www.whatismyip.com/**

**And Now Check Your System Ip Address ( Internal Ip Address using  ipconfig in  `cmd` )**

Both Are Differect So You Need To Used `Public Ip Address` Which One You Get From https://www.whatismyip.com

Now, you have to Give Access permission to Database for Specific iP Address, By Default Mysql is not allowing to Access it SO You Need To Fire This Command for .

**Like This :**

```
SQL> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'your_database_pc_public_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

**Example::**

```
 SQL> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'any_name'@'public_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'any_password';
```

Then Its Work  Fine For You :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
   $dbServerName = "DNS Name  or  ip address";
   $dbUsername = "username";
   $dbPassword = "password";
   $dbName = "dbname";

   // create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($dbServerName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

   // check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) 
   {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   echo "Connected successfully";
 ?>
```

Comment: I did the change but I did: "
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out"

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to connect remote MySQL Server Using PHP, what you have to do is:

1. Create a MySQL User in remote server.
2. Give Full privilege to the User:

   - firewall of the server must be set-up to enable incomming connections on port 3306
   - you must have a user in MySQL who is allowed to connect from `%` (any host) (see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) for details)
3. Connect to the Server using PHP Code (Sample Given Below)

```php
$link = mysql_connect('your_my_sql_servername or IP Address', 'new_user_which_u_created', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

mysql_select_db('sandsbtob',$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
// we connect to localhost at port 3306
```

Comment: for editing mysql privileges:
mysql> CREATE USER 'usr'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testDb.* TO 'monty'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: To bad the deprecated mysql_* functions are used in the answer.

Comment: I did the change but I did: "Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead" and "Warning: mysql_connect(): Connection timed out"